# There's some way to create a line from a string split

Tags: python, pandas

I need your help on something like this:

My input (when I read .csv file):

[image]

```
data = {'A':['000','001','002'],
   'B':['Name0','Name1','Name2 @35 @DI @003 @Name3 @68 @DI'],
   'C':[27,24,35],
   'D':['@DI','@DI','@DI']}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

My desired output:

[image]

I don't know how to explain better than this.

I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

```
data = {'A':['000','001','002','003'],
   'B':['Name0','Name1','Name2','Name3'],
   'C':[27,24,35,68],
   'D':['@DI','@DI','@DI','@DI']}
```

Comment: It is very very unclear what you want to do

Comment: Dont post images, post copy-paste friendly tables. Ideally, you should post the code required to create that dataframe, so people can create it locally. You will have more chances to get help that way.

Comment: Thanks for help, added the dataframe coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a physical work rather than a technical work:)

```py
entry_list = df.loc[2, 'B'].split(' ')
df.loc[2, 'B'] = entry_list[0]
entry_list = entry_list[3:]
lines = []
for i in range(0, len(entry_list), 4):
    raw_line = entry_list[i:i+4]
    line = [item.replace('@', '') for item in raw_line[:-1]]
    line.append(raw_line[-1])
    lines.append(line)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=df.columns)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: It works well which I need. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string based on '@'. Then you need to group them (split function will do that). Finally, Change the value of required columns and use pd.explode to get the result.

check if that's what you need, then I can explain in detail.

```
df['split'] = df['B'].str.split('@')
def split(id,x):
    if len(x) <= 1:
        return np.NaN
    a_list = [id]
    b_list = []
    c_list = []
    d_list = []
    for index,i in enumerate(x):
        if index % 4 == 0:
            b_list.append(i)
        elif (index+1)%4 == 0:
            a_list.append(i)
        elif (index+2) % 4 ==0:
            i = '@' + str(i)
            d_list.append(i)
        else:
            c_list.append(i)
    return [a_list,b_list,c_list,d_list]
            
        
df['split'] = df.apply(lambda x: split(x['A'],x['split']), axis=1)

# df[]=df['split'].str[1]
df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'A'] = df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'split'].str[0]
df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'B'] = df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'split'].str[1]
df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'C'] = df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'split'].str[2]
df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'D'] = df.loc[(~df['split'].isnull()), 'split'].str[3]
df = df.drop('split', axis=1)
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

**Output -**

```
      A       B    C     D
0   000   Name0   27   @DI
1   001   Name1   24   @DI
2   002  Name2   35   @DI 
2  003   Name3   68    @DI
```

Comment: It's a great answer too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It'll work for any number of rows that follow the same pattern. :)